# @FormDataParam lanza excepción SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public

Tags: java, rest, jersey, postman, jax-rs

Estoy intentando enviar un fichero .xlsx como parámetro a una llamada POST mediante Postman. En mi api, lo tengo definido así:

```
@POST
@Path("/usuario/{token}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@ApiOperation(value = "Update excel", notes = "Update excel", response = JSONObject.class)
public JsonResponse updateExcel(
        @ApiParam(name = "token", value = "token assigned to session", required = true) @PathParam("oken") String token,
        @ApiParam(name = "excelFichero", value = "Fichero excel", required = true) @FormDataParam("excelFichero") InputStream excelFichero)
```

En el pom.xml he añadido la dependencia jersey-multipart:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

La versión de jersey que utilizo es la 1.19. Según he estado investigando, las versiones tienen que coincidir, por lo tanto lo veo correcto. Este es el error que recibo:

```
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public org. ...(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.io.InputStream) at parameter at index 2
SEVERE: Method, public org. ...(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.io.InputStream), annotated with POST of resource, class org. ..., is not recognized as valid resource method.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solución por mí misma. Sólo tuve que quitar la anotación @ApiParam del fichero:

```
public JsonResponse updateExcel(
    @ApiParam(name = "token", value = "token assigned to session", required = true) @PathParam("token") String token,
    @FormDataParam("excelFichero") InputStream excelFichero)
```